# Faraday's Law of Induction - Two Versions

Tags: electromagnetism, electromagnetic-induction, calculus

Does anyone know why Faraday's Law for the transformer $emf$ is sometimes written as showing the partial derivative of $B$ with respect to time INSIDE the integral, and sometimes $\frac{\mathrm{d}}{\mathrm{d}t}$ (not partial) is OUTSIDE the integral?

$$\int \frac{\partial B}{\partial t} \cdot \mathrm{d}S$$ vs $$\frac{\mathrm{d}}{\mathrm{d}t} \int B \cdot \mathrm{d}S$$

Some sources have claimed that these are equivalent, but I've worked on several problems in my electromagnetics class where they give different results.

What is the reasoning behind the different versions and what is the intuition behind using one over the other?

Answer (score 3):

The field is a function of multiple variables: $\mathbf B=\mathbf B(\mathbf r,t)$. Therefore, a derivative of the field with respect to time will be denoted by a partial derivative $\partial/\partial t$ rather than a total derivative.

However, if we integrate the field over a specific surface in space, we remove the dependency on the spatial variables; the flux only depends on time. Therefore, we use a total derivative $\text d/\text dt$.

These two are equivalent because the surface over which the integral is done does not have a time dependence, so we can move the derivative with respect to time inside or outside the integral as desired.

Comment: would this change if the surface was moving through space, along with a time-varying B field? it seems to be that d/dt outside the integral is only applicable when the surface is stationary, i think